# Spring Boot to start with Oracle Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to use spring boot oracle with oracle configuration in application .properties

```
    spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521/XE/LocalDatabase
    spring.datasource.username=system
    spring.datasource.password=admin
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

    #hibernate config
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

I have the HibernateConfig for configuration and have normal Spring Boot Application

```
@Configuration        
    public class HibernateConfig {

        @Bean
        public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
             HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
             factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
             return factory;
        }
    }
```

```
    2017-04-22 07:37:50.287 ERROR 18480 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
    java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
    The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
    localhost:1521:orcl

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:441) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:165) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:143) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:340) [spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319) [spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at com.websystique.springboot.SpringBootCRUDApp.main(SpringBootCRUDApp.java:17) [classes/:na]

    2017-04-22 07:37:50.294  WARN 18480 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
    The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
    localhost:1521:orcl

    2017-04-22 07:37:50.323  INFO 18480 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    2017-04-22 07:37:50.400  INFO 18480 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
    2017-04-22 07:37:51.404 ERROR 18480 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

    java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
    The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
    localhost:1521:orcl

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:441) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:165) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:143) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$2.obtainConnection(SessionFactoryImpl.java:655) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:67) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:455) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:340) [spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319) [spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at com.websystique.springboot.SpringBootCRUDApp.main(SpringBootCRUDApp.java:17) [classes/:na]

    2017-04-22 07:37:51.406 ERROR 18480 --- [           main] org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper   : Unable obtain JDBC Connection

    java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
    The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
    localhost:1521:orcl

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:441) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:165) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.4.0"]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:143) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$2.obtainConnection(SessionFactoryImpl.java:655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:340) [spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319) [spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:4.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at com.websystique.springboot.SpringBootCRUDApp.main(SpringBootCRUDApp.java:17) [classes/:na]

    2017-04-22 07:37:51.419  WARN 18480 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    2017-04-22 07:37:51.428  INFO 18480 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
    2017-04-22 07:37:51.446  INFO 18480 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2017-04-22 07:37:51.451 ERROR 18480 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1589) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: What are the contents of your listener.ora file?

Comment: listener.ora is irrelevant. Url should simply be: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE. You will connect to the default schema of the specified user.

Answer (score 1):

```
spring:
datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@DOMAIN.COM:1521:XE
    username: username
    password: password
```

Above configuration is sufficient as of Spring Boot 2.0.3. We could use these properties if needed.I have used YAML and not properties. I guess you can relate.

```
driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make some modifications for `listener.ora`. Refer to [this link](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_4a5ad9270100nb7p.html) to modify the `SID_LIST_LISTENER`.